# How to clone a remote git repository such that all branches will be downloaded

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I am new to Git, and still learning it.
I am trying to clone a Git remote repository called `hello-world` to my local machine.

On the remote (github in this case) the repository has two branches

1. `Main`
2. `Branch1`

But when I clone this repository and enter the command `git branch` it shows the `main` branch only.

I learned that with `--branch` for the `clone` command I can tell git to explicitly download another branch than the default. It works as expected, so when I `git clone https://github.com/ShivMahla/hello-world.git --branch branch1`, git downloads the repository with that `branch1`, however this time I found `main` is missing when I am using `git branch` command.

Please let me know what mistake I am doing.

I am expecting both branches should come to my local system and when I use `git branch` command it should show two entries to me

1. main/master
2. branch1

Do I need to make any setting in GitHub account for this?

Comment: Well it didn't when I typed that comment. But I don't insist.

Answer (score 1):

The short version:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/<me>/<myRepo>
cd myRepo
git switch branch1
```

From [git switch man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

In your case, `origin/branch1` does exist, so switching to branch1 will automatically tracks `origin/branch1`

`git branch` will show you both local branches.
And `git branch -avv` will show you both local and remote tracking branches.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot here, but let's start with two things:

1. GitHub is not Git.  GitHub is a site that lets you *store* Git repositories, and that *adds on* a bunch of features that are not present in base Git.
2. Your issue here is with base Git.  That's what you need to learn first (or at the same time).  You've tagged your question with four tags: [git](/questions/tagged/git), [github](/questions/tagged/github), [github-actions](/questions/tagged/github-actions), and [github-cli](/questions/tagged/github-cli).  This isn't appropriate at this point as your real question is an elementary one about Git.  I'll snip off all but the [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag.

There are many things to know about Git, too, but let's start with this one thing: **When you clone an existing Git repository with `git clone` on the command line, you normally get *all* of their commits, and *none* of their branches.**  But your `git clone` command ends, before returning control to you, by:

- *Creating* **one** branch in *your clone*.  This branch name is *yours*.  It is not some other Git's branch name.  It is yours to do with as you wish.
- "Checking out" this one branch.  That results in the normal *attached HEAD* state.

The branch name that your Git *creates* is the one you supply on the command line: `-b branch1`, for instance, tells your Git to create a local branch name `branch1`.

If you don't supply a `-b` argument, your Git asks their Git—the Git holding the repository you're cloning—which branch name *they* recommend.  They tend to recommend the branch named `main` or `master`, with the details depending on exactly who "they" are and how things are configured there.

There are a bunch of exceptions to the above rules.  For instance, you can supply a *tag* name to your `-b` argument; when you do this, your Git creates *no* branches, and with no branches, you cannot be in the normal "attached HEAD" state and so you're left in *detached HEAD* state, using the tag name.  (Tag names get shared across multiple different clones, unlike branch names.)  Fortunately you're not doing this so we don't have to worry about it.  There is also a thorny problem with *totally empty* repositories, or you can clone with a flag that says *do not create any branches*, but again, you're not doing this and we don't have to worry about it.

What you *do* need to know here is that after your Git copies all the *commits* from the other Git over at GitHub, your Git takes all of their *branch names*—`branch1` and `main`, for instance—and *changes those names into remote-tracking names*.  In this case, your Git turns their `main` into your `origin/main`, and turns their `branch1` into your `origin/branch1`.  Your Git then creates or updates these *remote-tracking* names to remember the same commit hash IDs that *their* Git is remembering via their *branch* names.

**The takeaway here is that your Git turns their *branch* names into your *remote-tracking* names.  You therefore end up with just one *branch* name, from your `-b` argument, even if they have hundreds of branches in their Git repository.**  Your Git can create a new branch name from any of your remote-tracking names later, if and when you choose to do so.